# How can we say that Oracle supports physical data independence?

Tags: oracle

To be an RDBMS it should support physical data independence as stated by E.F.Codd. So how can we state that Oracle supports it..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: For my part I am voting to migrate it to stack DBA. It's an interesting question, but not a programming issue.

Comment: It's not really a "Database Administration" question either. I don't think there is any stack exchange site that really covers this area. Perhaps Computer Science?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate Physical data independence:

1. Export a schema from database A
2. Import dumped schema to database B
3. The SQL statements which ran on database A will run on database B without any  changes.

To demonstrate Logical data independence

1. user B runs `select col1 from a.t42;`
2. user A adds a new column: `alter table t42 add col23 date;`
3. user B doesn't notice: `select col1 from a.t42;` still works